# Create test table and data in DB2

Tags: db2

How I can create table with 10 MB test data in DB2 Express-C ?

Can you show me some basic example how to insert random data?

```
 CREATE TABLE topic_sources (
  topic_id integer NOT NULL,
  platform varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  keywords varchar(50) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (topic_id,platform)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive query for that, something like

```
insert into topic_sources (topic_id, platform, keywords)
with tmp (i) as (
  select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1
  union all
  select i+1 from tmp where i < 1000000
)
select 
  int(rand()*10000), 
  'platform'||int(rand()*10), 
  'keyword'||int(rand()*100)
from tmp
```

Adjust the random number ranges and the number of rows as appropriate.

The idea is taken from [here (slide 14)](http://www.slideshare.net/NickIvanov2/sql-tips-and-techniques-april-2014).

Comment: The topic_id generated should probably not be random, as you stand a pretty decent chance of getting a duplicate, which will then fail.